# Loop through list to find element and add total of price based on that element?

Tags: python, list, loops, indexing

I want to be able to loop through a list to find matches of elements within the list that is written to file and add the total of prices given for the element in the list. Here is what I have so far - just don't know how to find matches of elements and add. - E.g. your expense name lists might contain multiple entries called "junk food" and for each there will be a corresponding priceList entry for its cost.

```
def expensesManager():
  filePath=pickAFile()
  file=open(filePath,"w")
  numExpenses=requestInteger("How many weekly expenses do you currently have?")
  expensePriceList=[None]*numExpenses
  expenseNameList=[None]*numExpenses
  index=0
  total=0  
  while(index<numExpenses):
    expenseNameList[index]=requestString("Name of Expense "+str(index+1))
    expensePriceList[index]=requestNumber("Price of "+ str(expenseNameList[index].capitalize())+" per week")
    lineList=(expenseNameList[index].capitalize()+" "+str(expensePriceList[index])+"\n")
    total=expensePriceList[index]

    print "Your total expenditure on "+str(expenseNameList[index]).capitalize()+ " per month is $"+str((total)*4)
    file.writelines(lineList)

    index=index+1


  file.close()
```

Comment: Could you provide a sample of what is in the list that you are looping through?

Comment: @WillP expenseNameList is the list I want to loop through. So if I enter "bills" twice in the requestString function it recognises that I have entered this twice and totals the two different amounts of "bills" that I enter in the requestNumber function.

Comment: And by sample, Will P meant some sample data and not the name of that data

Comment: Look at for loops and dictonarys. This looks like what you need.

Comment: @thatrockbottomprogrammer 

expenseNameList = [bills, car, Uni, bills]
expensePriceLIst = [300, 150, 470, 150]
I want to be able to add the two elements related to bills e.g 300 and 150

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code that will combine the two lists into a default dictionary. Then loop through and fetch the sum of each element price. 
You can implement this into your personal code.

```
expenseNameList = ['bills', 'car', 'Uni', 'bills'] 
expensePriceLIst = [300, 150, 470, 150]

    #Created defultdict 

from collections import defaultdict
diction = defaultdict(set)
for c, i in zip(expenseNameList, expensePriceLIst):
    diction[c].add(i)

for x in diction:
  print ("Your total expenditure on",x, "per month is $"+str(sum(diction.get(x)))+".")
```

Comment: thanks for the response, is there a way to do it without dictionary? I'll try this just to see how it works and whether I could modify into for loop without using dictionary.

Comment: Yes, i have pos7ted a working code only using lists. And I have edited my dictionary code, as it was not working. Now both should work fine

Answer (score 0):

Wow your request to make it only work with lists was odd, as a dictionary would work far better. But here it is. A working code that only uses lists.

```
expenseNameList = ['bills', 'car', 'Uni', 'bills'] 
expensePriceLIst = [300, 150, 470, 150]
TotalPrice = []

for x in expenseNameList:
  b = [item for item in range(len(expenseNameList)) if expenseNameList[item] == x]
  tempprice = 0
  tempname = 0
  for i in b:
    tempprice = expensePriceLIst[i] + tempprice
    tempname = expenseNameList[i]
  a = ("Your total expenditure on "+tempname+ " per month is $"+str(tempprice)+".")
  if a not in TotalPrice:
    TotalPrice.append(a)
for x in TotalPrice:
  print(''.join(x))
```

Comment: hi @willp above code brings up following output "Your total expenditure on 0 per month is $0."